# Get resolved data from service within a service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

How do I resolve the $promise generated by apiResource inside getDB() before it's actually returned back to my controller?  Right now I get undefined.

```
 people.factory('uniqueContacts', ['apiResource', function(apiResource) {
  return{
  getDB: function () {
    apiResource.query({api_resource:'people'}).$promise.then(function(response){ 
     return response.data
   });
  }
}
 }]);

 $resolvedData = uniqueContacts.getDB();
 console.log($resolvedData);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things:

- first your function needs to actually return something
- second here you have an async process so you'll need a callback, you cannot simply store the return in a variable like that

Check that code instead:

```
people.factory('uniqueContacts', ['apiResource', function(apiResource) {
  return {
    getDB: function () {
      return apiResource.query({api_resource:'people'}).$promise.then(function(response){ 
        return response.data
      });
    }
  };
}]);

uniqueContacts.getDB().then(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: so as an aside, how could I resolve getDB within another service method. For example, say I had a manipulateData method that needed resolved data of this.getDB

Comment: @JustinYoung: you call it like I did and launch `manipulateData(data)` inside the `.then(function (data) {—})` block

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like that. I made async the function getDB.

```
people.factory('uniqueContacts', ['apiResource','$q', function(apiResource,$q) {
  return{
  getDB: function () {
    var d = $q.defer
    apiResource.query({api_resource:'people'}).then(function(response){ 
     d.resolve(response);
   },function(err){
     d.reject(err);
    });
  }
}
 }]);

uniqueContacts.getDB().then(function(response){
  $resolvedData = response;
  console.log($resolvedData);
});
```

If you want to wait for the async call to be finished, add a promise table and wait for $q.all like that.

```
var promises = [];
promise.push(uniqueContacts.getDB().then(function(response){
  $resolvedData = response;

}));
$q.all(promises).then(function(){
   console.log($resolvedData);
});
```